# Using new JPA on conditions for one to many mappings

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, jpa-2.1

JPA 2.1 has been released recently and a new feature seems to be on conditions.

I found it mentioned in [some blogs](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft) and the [Eclipselink documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON).

How can I make use of this?

I have two entities linked to each other with @OneToMany and @JoinColumn. However I have to filter out some of the second entities.

The blog sample shows:

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
  FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p
    ON p.status = 'inStock'
 GROUP BY s.name
```

How can I make use of this for my mappings?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ON clause is for queries, not mappings.

If you want to add an additional criteria to a mapping, this is not something that JPA supports in the spec.

With EclipseLink you can do this using a DescriptorCustomizer and setting the mapping's selectionCriteria.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria

Comment: I already guessed those are two very different animals. I wanted to stay free for implementation dependent stuff, but I will have a look at it.